# Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "все равно"?

Tags: пунктуация

-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оборот "все равно" выделяется запятой только, если стоит в начале предложения. В остальных случаях - не выделяется.

Answer (score 1):

Все равно не является вводным; других оснований, чтобы выделять его в начале предложения ли где-либо еще, я не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

Нет никакой причины и разумных объяснений для запятой.

Answer (score 1):

"Всё равно" можно принять как грамматическую основу
"Всё" - подлежащее, "равно" - сказуемое
По этому, по-мойму, оно выделяется запятыми

Comment: Поэтому - слитно, по - моему - через дефис.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это зависит от интонации: если выделяется голосом, можно поставить запятую...

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, "всё равно" - это одно из синтаксически неделимых или фразеологических сочетаний, когда лексическое значение имеет только весь оборот в целом. Запятыми он, отдельно взятый, не выделяется, если только не входит  в состав другого оборота.